# problems with input element's value getting updated when ng-model is dynamically generated

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I have an array of objects

```
self.components = [{componentId:'', name:'', value:''}];
$scope.components = [{componentId:'', name:'', value:''}];
```

Each component is pushed to the array dynamically like below

```
for(var i=0; i<d.length; i++){
                        $scope.licenseComponents.push(d[i]);
                        self.licenseComponents.push(d[i]);
                        $scope.components.push({componentId:d[i].licenseComponentDefId, name:d[i].name, value:''});
                        self.components.push({componentId:d[i].licenseComponentDefId, name:d[i].name, value:''});
                    }
```

After this array is built, components[i].value of each array object is set to ng-model dynamically like below and the generated HTML looks like below.

```
var ip = document.createElement("input"); //input element, text
var label = document.createElement("label");
ip.setAttribute('type',"text");
var id = "id";
id = id.concat(self.licenseComponents[i].licenseComponentDefId);
ip.setAttribute('id', id );
var ngModel = "components[";
ngModel = ngModel.concat(i);
ngModel = ngModel.concat("].value");
ip.setAttribute('ng-model',ngModel);
form.appendChild(ip);
form.appendChild(label);
var myNode = document.getElementsByTagName('div').namedItem("dynamicElements");
myNode.appendChild(form);
```

[image: generated HTML]

But $scope.components.value does not get updated when value is typed in to input text element. Can someone point out what is going wrong here? 
TIA

Comment: why don't you use ng-repeat to create your labels and inputs?

Comment: The thing is I may not always have input elements, it could be input or select or any other element type. I have a if condition like below                 if (self.licenseComponents[i].componentTypeId == 1){ } If the type is 1, its a input element.

Comment: Instead of the ng-model, I just did document.getElementById(id) which works. But I still can't get ng-model working.